# Handling multi-dimensional POST data in C# (ASP.NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I've created a matrix-type form with dynamic rows and columns. The cells contain input fields that need to be handled by C# (MVC4, ASP.NET 4). The form looks like this (simplified):

```
<form action="~/Administration/PriceMatrix" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Prices[1][0][1]" value="15.00" />
    <input type="text" name="Prices[1][0][2]" value="12.50" />
    <input type="text" name="Prices[1][1][1]" value="10.00" />
    <input type="text" name="Prices[1][1][2]" value="7.50" />
</form>
```

The matching controller is still empty:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PriceMatrix(object form)
{

}
```

When I use `Request.Form` I can of course access all the values, but they're not (de)serialized into an array. So I cannot do this: `Request.Form["Prices"][0]` or something like that. Instead, I can only access them using their full names: `Request.Form["Prices[1][0][1]"]` (=15.00). Of course I can loop thru the array and split the `Key` for each value, but I would like to do it some other way. I've tried to replace `object form` with another type or custom object containing lists etc., but so far no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried something like "`double[,,] prices`" as a parameter? just wondering... no idea if that works

Comment: why are you not serializing the form into JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the values as custom type. I suggest you to serialize your form to JSON, and then on server side access the serialized form in any way you like.